# mysql update for five tables

Tags: sql, database, join

I have looked and looked, mostly at UPDATE with multiple tables.  Once or twice I searched specificially with 5 tables.  The examples mostly show only two tables.

When I run the code below I get this message:
update for memret 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(M.first = test, M.last = nine, M.address1 = 999 woodland, M.zip = 21122, M.emai' at line 5
From my research this happens to many.  I have switched around the code numerous times.  This is my latest stab at what might fly but it crashed with the same message as above.

This code is below followed by the mysql db record.

Help please!

```
$sql = "UPDATE membership AS M
        LEFT JOIN address2 AS A2 ON M.memno1 = A2.memno2
      LEFT JOIN contact AS Con ON M.memno1 = Con.memno3
        LEFT JOIN workers AS W ON M.memno1 = W.memno4
      LEFT JOIN comments AS Com ON M.memno1 = Com.memno5";
$sql.=" SET (M.first = $first, M.last = $last, M.address1 = $address1,";               
$sql.=" M.zip = $zip, M.email = $email, M.password = $password,";
$sql.=" M.secq = $secq,M.seca = $seca,";
$sql.=" A2.address2 = $address2,";
$sql.=" Con.home = $home, Con.cell = $cell, Con.work = $work,";
$sql.=" W.webhelp = $webhelp, W.locorg = $locorg, W.candasst = $candasst,";
$sql.=" W.loccam = $loccam, W.other = $other, W.otherexp = $otherexp,";
$sql.=" Com.comment = $comment) WHERE memno1=$memno";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("update for memret 1: ".mysql_error());
```

memno1  first   last    address1    zip email   password    secq    seca    memno2  address2    memno3  home    cell    work    memno4  webhelp locorg  candasst    loccam  other   otherexp    memno5  comment memno6  office  first   last    address1    address2    zip
9   test    nine    999 woodland    21122   tn9@aol.com tn9999  house   wreck   9   dump    9   1232224444  333556666   2223335555  9   yes             yes ceo 9   test new side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **SQL injection**. If I read the error message correctly, `$address1` is `"999 woodland"` which will not be treated correctly by the SQL parser.

Stop substituting raw variables into query strings. (And stop using `mysql_*` functions, too. They're deprecated.) A prepared statement will go a long way here.

```
// assumes an existing PDO database connection in $conn
// requires exception-handling code (PDOException)
// requires you to check that e.g. integer fields will be updated with integers
$sql = "UPDATE membership AS M
  LEFT JOIN address2 AS A2 ON M.memno1 = A2.memno2
  LEFT JOIN contact AS Con ON M.memno1 = Con.memno3
  LEFT JOIN workers AS W ON M.memno1 = W.memno4
  LEFT JOIN comments AS Com ON M.memno1 = Com.memno5
  SET (M.first = :first, M.last = :last, M.address1 = :address1,
       M.zip = :zip, M.email = :email, M.password = :password,
       M.secq = :secq, M.seca = :seca,
       A2.address2 = :address2,
       Con.home = :home, Con.cell = :cell, Con.work = :work,
       W.webhelp = :webhelp, W.locorg = :locorg, W.candasst = :candasst,
       W.loccam = :loccam, W.other = :other, W.otherexp = :otherexp,
       Com.comment = :comment) WHERE memno1 = :memno";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$params = array(":first" => $first, ":last" => $last, ":address1" => $address1,
                ":zip" => $zip, ":email" => $email, ":password" => $password,
                ":secq" => $secq, ":seca" => $seca,
                ":address2" => $address2,
                ":home" => $home, ":cell" => $cell, ":work" => $work,
                ":webhelp" => $webhelp, ":locorg" => $locorg,
                ":candasst" => $candasst,
                ":loccam" => $loccam, ":other" => $other,
                ":otherexp" => $otherexp,
                ":comment" => $comment, ":memno" => $memno);
$did_we_succeed = $query->execute($params);
```

Comment: many thanks michaelb958. I did some looking with key words in your answer and I got a completely different outlook on the PDO.  I took the easy way out which bit me. I printed out some info to learn about the PDO way.

Comment: I have done a lot of changing my code so I'm going to ask a new question because I don't understand the "bind" error message I am getting.  Thanks @michaelb958.  Hope to hear from you on the next question.